# How to calculate sensitivity of feature vector for binary variable flipping

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, python, computational-statistics

I need to calculate the "sensitivity" of a vector of binary data in order to flip a binary result (1,0) given an array of coefficients derived from a LinearSVC model.

For example, let's say I have an instance vector **[1,0,0,1,0]** which outputs **y=1**, and the coefficients I got from the LinearSVC model are **[-0.11,0.05,0.064,-0.0012,0.047].**

What I want to know is which variable/s are the most "sensitive" in order to flip the result to **y=0**, and if there is a way of calculating an overall metric of how "sensitive" the instance is to an output change.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. When you posted on SE, you gave up 
ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). If there are 
no answers, you may delete your own question (see 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)
): just click the faint gray 'delete' at lower left (your account needs to be 
registered for this). Otherwise, the thread will remain according to SE's rules.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of the coefficient is an indication of how much influence a particular factor has on the prediction.

The SVC can not only give a prediction (yes or no) but also a decision function, a number that is very positive for a definite yes, and very negative for a definite no. Values near to zero are close to the decision boundary, so easier to flip.